Camera Enable/ Disable option is not present in Raspberry pi

Camera Enable/ Disable option is not present in Raspberry pi 3 B+ model 
Camera module : Raspberry pi camera rev1.3
os :
uname -a
Linux dharanikanna 6.6.62+rpt-rpi-v8 #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 1:6.6.62-1+rpt1 (2024-11-25) aarch64 GNU/Linux
Ensured that Pi board and camera connection is also correct.
Below command used and bet the corresponding output
cmd : vcgencmd get_camera
output : supported=0 detected=0, libcamera interfaces=0
I have tried to do upgrade the packages, even no use.
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
Please help to enable camera option in raspberry pi.
